# ngrx: How to sync url and store data

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm starting to play with ngrx and i'm not clear on the concept of syncing changes made to url to store.

Let me explain. I have a store:

```
{
  "company": "AAA"
}
```

This value is needed in multiple components therefore it is present in the store.
And the application contains a dropdown where the user can change a company.

User change company in dropdown, store is updated, url is updated to `/company/BBB`. Container component can see BBB in store.

What is not clear is how to handle a situation when user hits `/company/BBB` directly? How to sync this to store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key concepts from NgRx is.

**SideEffects** are used for handle async operations, like HttpRequest for example.

**Reducer** are used for sync operations, like click event.

So what you can do is, as @j3ff suggest use router-store (quite overkill if you gonna use for few routes ). Or **dispatch an action** for that particular route when it's called to keep things easy to maintain.

Using router-store will be a quite time consumming if you need to implement quickly.

Remember what suit you best, for readability and easy to maintain you app.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@ngrx/router-store` which is made to bind Angular router with your store. During each router navigation cycle, multiple actions are dispatched that allows you to listen for changes in the router's state. You can then select data from the state of the router to provide additional information to your application.

See their documentation here: https://ngrx.io/guide/router-store